# Fixed-size C++ object pool, contiguous storage, O(1) random access, alloc and free. One header-only

Tags: c++, memory-management, template

I have implemented a rather simple object pool for the sake of entities in my game world, and it works quite well.

Advantages:

- Elements stay in contiguous memory - can be iterated just like in an array, at any time.
- Allocation, deallocation and dereference in `O(1)`.
- Freeing elements does not require updating existing ids.
- Id can always be safely queried if the element referred to was already freed.
- With a template argument, pool ids can be made 16, 8, 4, or 2 bytes wide depending on how many possible objects we require.

Disadvantages:

- While `O(1)`, dereferencing an element needs to fetch memory twice - firstly for the indirector array and secondly for the actual array of objects.
- There exists an astronomically low likelihood that an existing id starts pointing to a new object if enough allocations and deallocations happen with the same indirector, so that the values of `version` field make a full cycle - this is fine for a game, but if people's lives depend on it... I guess not.

I was wondering if I could tidy it up a little more.

Usage:

```
#include "pool.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; // just for the sake of example

template <class T>
using chosen_container = vector<T>;
using element_type = std::string;
using size_type = unsigned;

int main() {
    pool<element_type, chosen_container, size_type> p;

    p.allocate("First");
    p.allocate("Second");

    const auto id = p.allocate("I'll be dead");
    assert(p.alive(id));

    p.allocate("Third");

    assert(p.size() == 4);
    p.free(id);
    assert(p.dead(id));
    assert(p.size() == 3);

    p.allocate("I'll be in place of the dead");

    cout << "In pool: " << endl;

    for (const auto& object : p) {
        cout << object << endl;
    }

    p.for_each_object_and_id([](const auto& object, const auto id) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Object value: " << object << endl;
        cout << "Pointing id indirector: " << id.indirection_index << endl;
        cout << "Object version: " << id.version << endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
In pool:
First
Second
Third
I'll be in place of the dead

Object value: First
Pointing id indirector: 0
Object version: 1

Object value: Second
Pointing id indirector: 2
Object version: 1

Object value: Third
Pointing id indirector: 6
Object version: 1

Object value: I'll be in place of the dead
Pointing id indirector: 1
Object version: 2
```

`pool.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <cassert>

// Templatize by T so that it can't be used with an incompatible pool.
// These structures could be nested in pool, but I need to forward-declare them for introspection code.
template <class T, class size_type>
struct pooled_object_id {
    size_type version = 0;
    size_type indirection_index = -1;
};

template <class size_type>
struct pool_slot {
    size_type pointing_indirector = -1;
};

template <class size_type>
struct pool_indirector {
    size_type real_index = 0;
    size_type version = 1;
};

template <
    class T,
    template <class> class make_container_type,
    class size_type
>
class pool {
public:
    using mapped_type = T;
    using key_type = pooled_object_id<mapped_type, size_type>;

protected:
    using pool_slot = pool_slot<size_type>;
    using pool_indirector = pool_indirector<size_type>;

    make_container_type<pool_slot> slots;
    make_container_type<mapped_type> objects;
    make_container_type<pool_indirector> indirectors;
    make_container_type<size_type> free_indirectors;

    auto& get_indirector(const key_type key) {
        return indirectors[key.indirection_index];
    }

    const auto& get_indirector(const key_type key) const {
        return indirectors[key.indirection_index];
    }

    bool correct_range(const key_type key) const {
        return
            key.indirection_index != -1 // Quickly eliminate fresh ids without fetching indirectors.size()
            && key.indirection_index < indirectors.size()
            ;
    }

    bool versions_match(const pool_indirector& indirector, const key_type key) const {
        return indirector.version == key.version;
    }

public:
    pool(const size_type slot_count = 0u) {
        reserve(slot_count);
    }

    void reserve(const size_type new_capacity) {
        const auto old_capacity = capacity();

        if (new_capacity <= old_capacity) {
            return;
        }

        slots.reserve(new_capacity);
        objects.reserve(new_capacity);

        indirectors.resize(new_capacity);
        free_indirectors.reserve(new_capacity);

        for (size_type i = old_capacity; i < new_capacity; ++i) {
            free_indirectors.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    template <
        unsigned expansion_mult = 2,
        unsigned expansion_add = 1,
        class... Args
    >
    key_type allocate(Args&&... args) {
        if (full()) {
            const auto old_size = size();
            const auto new_size = std::size_t(old_size) * expansion_mult + expansion_add;

            assert(new_size <= std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max());

            reserve(static_cast<size_type>(new_size));
        }

        const auto next_free_indirector = free_indirectors.back();
        free_indirectors.pop_back();

        const auto new_slot_index = size();

        pool_indirector& allocated_indirector = indirectors[next_free_indirector];
        allocated_indirector.real_index = new_slot_index;

        key_type allocated_id;
        allocated_id.version = allocated_indirector.version;
        allocated_id.indirection_index = next_free_indirector;

        pool_slot allocated_slot;
        allocated_slot.pointing_indirector = next_free_indirector;

        slots.push_back(allocated_slot);
        objects.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        return allocated_id;
    }

    bool free(const key_type key) {
        if (!correct_range(key)) {
            return false;
        }

        auto& indirector = get_indirector(key);

        if (!versions_match(indirector, key)) {
            return false;
        }

        // add dead key's indirector to the list of free indirectors
        free_indirectors.push_back(key.indirection_index);

        // therefore we must increase version of the dead indirector
        ++indirector.version;

        const auto removed_at_index = indirector.real_index;

        if (const bool need_to_move_last = removed_at_index != size() - 1) {
            const auto indirector_of_last_element = slots.back().pointing_indirector;

            // change last element's indirector - set it to the removed element's index
            indirectors[indirector_of_last_element].real_index = removed_at_index;

            slots[removed_at_index] = std::move(slots.back());
            objects[removed_at_index] = std::move(objects.back());
        }

        slots.pop_back();
        objects.pop_back();

        return true;
    }

    mapped_type& get(const key_type key) {
        assert(correct_range(key));

        const auto& indirector = get_indirector(key);

        assert(versions_match(indirector, key));

        return objects[indirector.real_index];
    }

    const mapped_type& get(const key_type key) const {
        assert(correct_range(key));

        const auto& indirector = get_indirector(key);

        assert(versions_match(indirector, key));

        return objects[indirector.real_index];
    }

    mapped_type* find(const key_type key) {
        if (!correct_range(key)) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        const auto& indirector = get_indirector(key);

        if (!versions_match(indirector, key)) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        return &objects[indirector.real_index];
    }

    const mapped_type* find(const key_type key) const {
        if (!correct_range(key)) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        const auto& indirector = get_indirector(key);

        if (!versions_match(indirector, key)) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        return &objects[indirector.real_index];
    }

    bool alive(const key_type key) const {
        return correct_range(key) && versions_match(get_indirector(key), key);
    }

    bool dead(const key_type key) const {
        return !alive(key);
    }

    mapped_type* data() {
        return objects.data();
    }

    const mapped_type* data() const {
        return objects.data();
    }

    auto size() const {
        return static_cast<size_type>(slots.size());
    }

    auto capacity() const {
        return static_cast<size_type>(indirectors.size());
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    bool full() const {
        return size() == capacity();
    }

    template <class F>
    void for_each_object_and_id(F f) {
        key_type id;

        for (size_type i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            const auto& s = slots[i];
            id.indirection_index = s.pointing_indirector;
            id.version = indirectors[s.pointing_indirector].version;

            f(objects[i], id);
        }
    }

    template <class F>
    void for_each_object_and_id(F f) const {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            key_type id;

            const auto& s = slots[i];
            id.indirection_index = s.pointing_indirector;
            id.version = indirectors[s.pointing_indirector].version;

            f(objects[i], id);
        }
    }

    template <class F>
    void for_each_id(F f) {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            key_type id;

            const auto& s = slots[i];
            id.indirection_index = s.pointing_indirector;
            id.version = indirectors[s.pointing_indirector].version;

            f(id);
        }
    }

    template <class F>
    void for_each_id(F f) const {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            key_type id;

            const auto& s = slots[i];
            id.indirection_index = s.pointing_indirector;
            id.version = indirectors[s.pointing_indirector].version;

            f(id);
        }
    }

    auto begin() {
        return objects.begin();
    }

    auto begin() const {
        return objects.begin();
    }

    auto end() {
        return objects.end();
    }

    auto end() const {
        return objects.end();
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you seen the videos on Mario 64 by Pannenkoek? 64 has a very similarly laid out object pooling system.

Comment: @CAD97 I didn't see it! It wasn't my idea though, I was inspired with some other post on gamedev.stackexchange :)

Comment: Yeah, it’s a common pattern. Thus why there’s always a library that did it better (until you have _very_ specific needs).

Comment: @CAD97 Out of curiosity, is there an established name for this pattern?

Comment: The pattern is an Object Pool. Another highly creative name from the computer industry ;) http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html

Comment: @CAD97 The one you linked is a different approach, as it does not keep all living particles in contiguous storage. I've however just found my pattern here: https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/game-engine-containers-handle-map-r4495 It goes by the name "handle_map", but apparently the term is not yet in wide use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Separation of concerns

Your class is a mix of an allocator and a container. There's no point in doing that. One class should do one focused thing.

Some of your functions (like `for_each_...`) are essentially a reimplementation of standard C++ algorithms (like `std::for_each`). Why would you add them?

## Proper vocabulary

An "allocator" term has a very precise meaning in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator. Your allocator is not exaclty an allocator, even though it uses a similar vocabulary (like the allocate function). It's quite confusing.

Moreover, the vocabulary of your class is not consistent. The words "allocate" and "dead"/"alive" have a different level of formalism. The whole indirector related thing is also not that easy to comprehend because there's no such notion in C++.

While these things might seem unimportant, they actually play a very big role in making your class easy (or hard) to use.

## Overall design and API

Your class's API is very complicated. It provides a lot of functions with similar names and slightly differnet behavior. It feels overwhelming. All an object pool needs to do is allocating and deallocating objects. That's it. Having more functions is not necessarily a good thing. Keep it simple and focused.

## The code itself

- The `max_size` function should be const.
- `// Check for overflow ... assert(new_size > old_size);`. It's broken (at least, it doesn't work for all multiplication coefficients). For instance, `2654574666 < 2654574666 * 3 % (2 ** 32) = 3668756702`, but the overflow does happen here.

## Is it worth having?

If your goal was to implement your own object pool, than it's fine.

If you have it for some other reasons (like performance or convenience), it's probably not. Firstly, it's definitely less convenient that a standard C++ container. Secondly, it may not be faster than a standard allocator. It might be even slower. Did you measure it? Did you have any performance issues in the first place. Anyway, implementing a custom allocator is the last thing I would do to tune the performance. Even if profiling shows that a standard allocator is too slow, I'd recommend to use an open source library with a custom allocator instead of implementing  your own.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! As for why I need it, the reason is that I need my entities stored in contiguous memory for quick copying, loading and saving large game worlds - I've actually measured that and it's way, way faster to do these operations on contiguous storage (as it is then as effective as a memcpy) than if they are allocated on the heap. On top of that, my entities may need to refer to other entities, so I needed some identification mechanism that would be as easily serializable, so references or pointers wouldn't cut it. That single class solves all these needs.

Comment: @PatrykCzachurski My point is that a single class shouldn't solve all these needs. You've named at least three concerns: allocation, storage in some kind of container and serialization. It's good reason to have three separate classes for each of them. It'll make the code easier to understand, reason about, test and reuse.

Comment: That's an interesting insight. I think I'll look into allocators more closely.
As for max_size and the overflow: You are perfectly right, I'll fix these immediately. About "dead/alive": would you have an idea on how to better name it? It should just return true if the object referred to by the argument still exists, or false if already freed. "exists/freed"? About for_each_id: it is not quite the same as std::for_each, because the callback is invoked not on an existing container; rather, a valid id for every allocated object is constructed upon which the callback is invoked.

Comment: @PatrykCzachurski I'd stick with one function (exists sounds fine to me). I don't think their's a point in having a function dead/freed because it's literally a negation of the former.